# Chef recipe to install System Center Endpoint Protection

Tags: chef-infra, scep

I want to install System Center Endpoint Protection (SCEP) using Chef Recipe in the Windows 2012 server. I am using the script below to install the exe file (`scepinstall.exe`). Looks like this is not the right recipe. Please help

```
windows_package 'SCEP' do
  source 'C:/foldername/scepinstall.exe'
  installer_type :custom
  options '/Q'
end
```

Comment: What does this do and how does that differ from your expectations?

Comment: It keeps on running and finally I have to end the task using task manager.

Comment: Are you sure the installer supports a headless or non-interactive install mode?

Comment: I'm not quite sure. This mode worked in the CloudFormation template.

Comment: I would check on that first.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think it's possible. My reference is the below link       https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2012/04/12/operating-system-deployment-and-endpoint-protection-client-installation/